# javax.servlet.ServletException in struts application

Tags: java, servlets, struts1

Got `javax.servlet.ServletException`: `java.lang.ClassCastException:com.dna.nsm.sim.action.LogoutAction`

in struts 1 application.

error message :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dna.nsm.sim.action.LogoutAction
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dna.nsm.sim.action.LogoutAction
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.CreateAction.createAction(CreateAction.java:98)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.CreateAction.getAction(CreateAction.java:68)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractCreateAction.execute(AbstractCreateAction.java:91)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
```

LogoutAction Code :

```
public class LogoutAction  extends Action{
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // To redirect to the Login page
        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
}
```

Struts-config.xml part

```
 <action path="/logout" type="com.dna.nsm.sim.action.LogoutAction" >
            <forward name="success" path="/tiles/login/body.jsp" />
 </action>
```

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports and make sure you're extending the right Action class.